# How do i close div and reopen in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am learning reactjs, and was making note taking app. Its working fine so far, but it isnt working when i close a note and then try to open same note again. If i open any other note than the one i closed it works fine.

I know that my if condition is causing this because i have below condition in my code `nextProps.note.id !== this.state.note.id` which only returns true if ids are different.

I tried many many variations but i am not able to implement note details and close feature all together. I know i am so close and just making some silly mistake, but i am not able to catch that mistake may be my reactjs understanding is weak.

If someone can point me in right direction or just give a clue that will be a great help, as i have spent many hours on this with no luck so far.

**Demo** : https://codesandbox.io/s/wqqklork

**How to recreate bug :** Click on note 1, then click close note button and then again click note 1 (this will not work), But if you click note 2 it will work.

Comment: Please note that recreation instructions don’t really mean anything to us since you haven’t provided any code for anyone to check.

Comment: Actually demo was ready but forgot to add link, its added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe its an issue with component lifecycle,when you click a new note a whole new component is rendered but when you click on the same component twice,the second time a new component is not rendered but the same same one is updated. Check on the willcomponentupdate lifecycle method .Hope that helps.

Comment: Its not when i click same note, its when i open a note, close that note and then click same note again.

Comment: Yeah the component displaying note details is no remounted but updated as it is  already mounted.

Comment: Glad I helped,take a look at the component lifecycle fully explained in the official documentation